# Merge from master to branch - Git/Jenkins

Tags: git, merge, jenkins

I am looking for a way to automate a merge from a Master branch to one or more development branches. In other words, I want to synchronise team development branches with Master daily across multiple projects.

I was looking into using Jenkins for this, but do not have much experience. Would Jenkins provide this functionality, perhaps by adding multiple repository URLs and then specifying the "branch to merge to" in the configuration? I am less concerned about the build of the project than merging issues. How would jenkins react to a failed merge?

Jenkins would be ideal, but if there is another approach I would love to hear it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly propose to have the dev responsible for the branch do this, as:

- A merge like this takes 10-30 seconds if there are no conflicts
- If there are conflicts, the person who knows how to resolve them is right there
- Your devs know best when to do this merge

Why would you want to automate this in the first place?

Comment: It was thought that this task would be a bit laborious for an individual developer to go through each project and attempt an merge and resolve any conflicts on a daily basis. The idea is to have an automated process highlight the projects which require manual intervention.

Comment: I don’t see how that’s easier – if there are no conflicts, it’s not really any work. And conflicts will have to be resolved anyways.

Comment: This has indeed been part of the discussion of late, I am unsure of this direction myself but have been asked to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) to manage merges onto a common and shared workstream.

Gerrit can be configured to use Jenkins to verify each changeset proposed for review.