# A script to merge the last successful build in jenkins from a development branch to a release branch using GIT

Tags: git, jenkins

Description:

1. Stability and automating function.
2. Every 2-3 hours Jenkins try to push a build.
3. Estimating around 8 build every 2-3 hours.
4. Jenkins will know if there is a good or bad code once the dev build is done.
5. Need to get the good builds and merge it with the code and exclude the bad one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge from master to branch - Git/Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566495/merge-from-master-to-branch-git-jenkins)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, listing a brief set of requirements does not make for a good question. It's helpful if you can narrow your question to a specific problem, rather than asking for SO to implement your task from scratch.